# Regex recognize cyrrilic word

Tags: c#, regex

I have string `test (strange) test - test - копія (121321)`
I need to recognize number in bruckets near the the `копія`

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"-\s\копія\s\((\d+)\)");
Match match = rgx.Match(newDoc.ConsignmentDocumentData.Content.DocumentName);
```

But it's throw Exception

> { "Parses \" - \ s \ копія\ s \ ((\ d +) \) \ "- Unrecognized
>   esc-sequence to the \к."}

How to fix it?

Comment: The exception puts it clear: "Unrecognized esc-sequence to the \к"; `\к` is invalid escape sequence, it should be just `к`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the backslash before `к`:

```
@"-\s*копія\s*\((\d+)\)"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%5Cs*%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F%5Cs*%5C%28%28%5Cd%2B%29%5C%29&i=test%20%28strange%29%20test%20-%20test%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F%20%28121321%29).

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/wwkULW):

```
var s = "test (strange) test - test - копія (121321)";
var pattern = @"-\s*копія\s*\((\d+)\)";
var result = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
if (result.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value); // => 121321
```